# react-query: How to fetch during the initial render and when an action is triggerd

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a component that fetches a bunch of posts. This has a set of filters too.

```
const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState(null);
const [selectedStatus, setSelectedStatus] = useState(null);

const getPosts = async (payload) => {
    const response = await fetchPosts(payload);
    return response;
};

const payload = {
  country: selectedCountry,
  status: selectedStatus,
};

const {isLoading, data: posts} = useQuery(['posts', payload], () => getPosts(payload));


const handleApplyFilters = () => {
  // refecth the posts with the applied filter payload
}

return (
  <>
    <select
        name="countryFilter"
        value={selectedCountry}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSelectedCountry(e.target.value);
        }}>
          <option>Singapore</option>
          <option>Finland</option>
          <option>Portugal</option>
    </select>
    
    <select
        name="statusFilter"
        value={selectedStatus}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSelectedStatus(e.target.value);
        }}>
          <option>Online</option>
          <option>Offline</option>
          <option>Blocked</option>
    </select>


    <button onClick={handleApplyFilters}>
      Apply Filters
    </button>
    
    {posts.map((post) => (
        <div>
          <div>{post.title}</div>
          <div>{post.description}</div>
        </div>
     ))}
  </>
)
```

I'm not sure how to achieve the following using react-query.

1. fetch posts only during the initial render
2. Avoid fetching posts on every filter change (only re-fetch when the `Apply Filter` button is clicked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got it right by putting the `payload` into the queryKey. Now all you want to do is update that local state not immediately when something is selected, but only when the user hits apply. For that, I would put the filter into it's own component with it's own state that will set the payload only when apply is clicked:

```
const [payload, setPayload] = React.useState(null)

const {isLoading, data: posts} = useQuery(['posts', payload], () => getPosts(payload));


<FilterForm onApply={setPayload} />
```

`FilterForm` will then contain the state for the two selections, and when the apply button is clicked, it will build the payload and call `onApply`, which will then call `setPayload` in the parent and thus trigger a re-fetch.